# Ionic Angularjs: dynamic styling on cards

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

**Context**:

I have cards that will be overlaid on a grid system to represent a time shift. The top part of the grid will pertain to certain time frames ( 1 pm 2 pm 3 pm etc. ) and the side will pertain to the people assigned to the shift. The cards normal state is just with a green top border. However when the person is on a break, I'd like for it to be blue, and when the person has been over scheduled, i'd like for it to be red.

I have to check the different break times and criteria to dynamically place the blue and red sections of the card.

**What I've tried**:

I've experimented with creating separate cards for each situation and stitching them together, but its not working cleanly. It is done using flex css.

I'd like to be able to just dynamically change only part of the card to the desired colors instead of stitching them together just because its seems more intuitive to me but I can't seem to search the right thing on google if it even exists.

The general question is what is the best way to go about this?

**EDIT**:
The final product would look like this.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into `ng-class` as it sounds as though it would suite your requirements.

It would allow you to do something like;

`<div ng-class="{'break': userOnBreak}">// code</div>`

Edit: `userOnBreak` being the variable stating wether your user is on a break or not (boolean).

Comment: Upon re-reading my question it was clear that i was very vague and not specific. Please see the edit.